# Como detectar quando o mouse está apontando para um botão

Tags: c#, winforms, button

Tenho um form onde determinadas ações serão executadas apenas quando um **button** `btn` tiver o cursor do mouse sobre ele, qual evento do botão eu uso ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o Evento `MouseHover` do Botão.

Para usa-lo, basta selecionar o botão que deseja adicionar a ação e na janela de Propriedades na barra superior click em Eventos (o ícone é um raio):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após os 2 click, automaticamente a IDE cria o evento e vc preenche com sua ação.

Um exemplo simples:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode tbm cria seu próprio evento e usa-lo logo após a inicialização dos componentes (`InitializeComponent();`).

veja como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tudo bem colocar prints demonstrando o resultado, mas o código é o principal, e deve ser postado como texto. =]

Comment: qual código vc quer ver @RovannLinhalis? Man o cara quer saber qual evento usar nada mais além disso. Se caso ele postasse o código a ser incrementado na ação, ai tudo bem! eu iria expor o evento com ação solicitada.